# Java Processbuilder - Catching the exitvalue of another Script?

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I try to run a python script in my java programm. What I want to do is to catch the exitValue of the python programm and write it via System.out.println out.

Here is the Python code:

```
import sys
import subprocess
print "hallo"
i = sys.argv[0]
path = "R:\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx\\read"
resultlist = []

if i == 0:
  result = True
else:
  result = False  

resultlist.append(result)
resultlist.append(path)
sys.exit(resultlist)
```

The Processbuilder methods .waitFor() and .exitValue() just gives a 0 or a 1 out. So I cant use it.

Is there any possible way to catch the value/string of sys.exit(resultlist) from the python script in my java programm?

Comment: Uh, of course not; the result of `exit()` is an integer. Your use of it is broken to start with

Comment: Thats not completly true, while running the script normally via cmd I'm getting the full text which should come out (resultlist).

Comment: Then that's a python trick; but it's not to be relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

`man 2 exit`:

```
The function _exit() terminates the calling process "immediately".  Any open file descriptors belonging to the process are closed; any children of the process
are inherited by process 1, init, and the process's parent is sent a SIGCHLD signal.

**The value status is returned to the parent process as the process's exit status, and can be collected using one of the wait(2) family of calls.**
```

You cannot return "complex values" with `exit(2)` (the syscall) to begin with. If python does that then fine, but it's a "trick". Don't rely on it.

What you want to do is print the output of your program to stdout and capture stdout. For this, use the `Process`'s `.getInputStream()` and swallow it in, for instance, a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Since you use a `ProcessBuilder`, you can also use its `.redirectOutput()` method before executing the process. Since Java 7, it has [quite a few options available](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput-java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect-).